# Python pandas - trying to a dict of df's into a panel (or loop the df items into a panel)

Tags: python, pandas, split, dataframe, multi-index

I have stock data in a dataframe with column headings like AAPL, AAPL_ma, MSFT, MSFT_ma -- and would like to somehow get the data into a panel with items = stock symbols (so AAPL item would include AAPL and AAPL_ma).

I am new to pandas and am struggling to come up with a coherent plan. I can't figure out if I should be: (1) working through MultiIndex functionality, (2) looping through lists to write data into new df's named as stock symbols, or (3) splitting the existing dataframe by symbol (eg, 'AAPL' in 'AAPL_ma').

Any direction would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

On EdChum's advise, I am using the following to create a dict of the column headings for my df in string form. Unsure if this is what you meant - work in progress.

```html
y = [df['Date']]
dict_stocks = {}
# create dict for multiindexing
for stock in list_stocks:
    i=0      
    x=[df[stock]]
    for heading in list_headings:
        data_series = df[stock + list_headings[i]]
        i = i + 1
        x.append(data_series)
    dict_stocks[stock] = y + x
```

The above produces a dict of df's, though the axes are not what I expected. However, I am having no luck with either of:

```html
my_panel = pd.Panel(df)
my_panel = pd.Panel.from_dict(dict_stocks)
```

which generate errors:

--PandasError: Panel constructor not properly called!

--AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Why not just take a list of the columns since you already have them: `list(df)`?

Comment: It makes sense to me to multiindex by symbol - so AAPL, AAPL_chg and AAPL_ma would all fall under AAPL. But I can't figure out how to execute using list(df).

Comment: Then why not make a dict of dfs using the symbol as the key

Comment: Thanks EdChum for your input. Still working on the big picture, but a step in the right direction.

Comment: Yes I think something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest way to the promised land would be to create a multi index dictionary with keys being tuples like (aapl, aapl) and (aapl,aapl_ma) and then doing a pandas.Dataframe() on the dictionary. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/advanced.html

If you want to do a panel I would recommend going with EdChums answer of creating a dict of dataframes with the key being the symbol, you can then use that dict to create a panel with pandas.Panel().

Comment: Skorp - thanks for posting. I have created the dict above in my update, but haven't yet had success pushing the data assoc with the dict keys back into a df or a panel.

Comment: I think you can just pass the dict into pandas.Panel(). So you would do p = pandas.Panel(your_dict). If your dict keys are tuples then you can do df = pandas.Dataframe(your_dict) this should result in one frame with a multi index.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I need to recreate the dict to contain each series instead of just the string column headings (as above, there is no data in what i did) - and then I will take your advise.